# MVVM в UWP: навигация и события

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

Переписываю своё старое `UWP`-приложение с использованием `паттерна MVVM`, возникли следующие проблемы:

---

***1. Навигация.***

В предыдущей версии для навигации между страницами я писал просто:

```
<Button Name="btSettings" Click="btSettings_Click"/>
```

и в CodeBehind:

```
private void btSettings_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
}
```

Как сделать это теперь? В `VM` я добавлю команду `OpenSettings`, например, и сделаю привязку:

```
<AppBarButton Icon="Setting" Label="Настройки" Command="{Binding OpenSettings}"/>
```

а что писать в методе команды? `Frame` в `VM`, естественно, недоступен

---

***2. Привязка команды к событию.***

Нужно после загрузки страницы выполнить команду, как это сделать?

В приложении `WPF` я делал примерно так:

```
xmlns:intr="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"

<intr:Interaction.Triggers>
    <intr:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadData}"/>
    </intr:EventTrigger>
</intr:Interaction.Triggers>
```

здесь, я так понимаю, эта сборка недоступна

Comment: 2) А то же самое в UWP не работает?

Comment: @VladD, к сожалению, недоступна эта сборка в UWP

Comment: Кстати, ведь привязка к событию Load и не нужна для вещей, не касающихся UI, можно ведь получить/загрузить данные из модели в конструкторе VM, только вот как это выполнить асинхронно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Написал собственный `NavigationService`:

   ```
   sealed class NavigationService
   {
       public void Navigate(Type sourcePage)
       {
           var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
           frame.Navigate(sourcePage);
       }

       public void Navigate(Type sourcePage, object parameter)
       {
           var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
           frame.Navigate(sourcePage, parameter);
       }

       public void GoBack()
       {
           var frame = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
           frame.GoBack();
       }

       private NavigationService() { }

       private static readonly Lazy<NavigationService> instance =
           new Lazy<NavigationService>(() => new NavigationService());

       public static NavigationService Instance => instance.Value;
   }
   ```

Теперь навигация выглядит примерно как у @MakeMakeluv, но без использования стороннего FW:

```
public ICommand NavigateToSettingsPage =>
    new DelegateCommand(o => NavigationService.Instance.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage)));
```

Надеюсь, это не идет вразрез `паттерна MVVM`, жду комментариев специалистов.

Comment: По-моему, вполне симпатично. Я, впрочем, не знаток UWP.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сказать совсем недавно (около года назад я думаю) для UWP ввели дополнительную фичу: `x:Bind` в дополнение к привычному `Binding`. И теперь без лишних телодвижений можно к любому событию привязывать метод из ViewModel.

Для примера, во ViewModel имеется свойство `isFriendSelected` для определения доступности выполнения метода `DeleteFriend`, тогда на событие `Click` на кнопке можно вызвать метод `DeleteFriend` из ViewModel так:

```
<Button Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.DeleteFriend}"
        IsEnabled="{x:Bind ViewModel.IsFriendSelected}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

По второй части вопроса: Interactions доступны и в UWP, под другими именем.
Вам нужен nuget-пакет `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`.

Ну и они там немного другие. Event'ов нету, но есть Behavior'ы. Так что ваш код по идее должен выглядеть так:

```
<Page
    x:Class="..."
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:..."
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    ...>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
            <core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
                <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadData}"/>
            </core:EventTriggerBehavior.Actions>
        </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Comment: В UWP к событиям теперь можно совсем просто привязывать методы из ViewModel через `x:Bind`

Answer (score 1):

По первому вопросу - если приложение содержит хотя бы страницы 3 имеет смысл не изобретать велосипеды, а воспользоваться фреймворком, например, Prism. Фреймворки как раз и сделаны для удобства рутинных операций типа навигации, хранения состояния и т.п.
Навигация в призме выглядит так:

```
public DelegateCommand NavigateToTargetPageCommand => new DelegateCommand(() => _navigationService.Navigate("Target", null));
```

Comment: Ого! А что такое `_navigationService`?

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, но прежде чем пользоваться готовым фреймворком нужно сделать всё это самому ручками хотя бы пару раз. Я так думаю.

Comment: @VladD это встроенный в `Prism` сервис типа `INavigationService`, инкапсулирующий всю логику навигации, который инжектится в ВМ через конструктор.